# orientdb OVER (PARTITION BY replacement

Tags: orientdb, graph-databases

I am porting over a DB instance from Oracle to OrientDB. In Oracle, we're using OVER (PARTITION BY to filter the data, but I haven't found a usable way to do this in OrientDB.

We have a table of Vehicles and a table of Locations. In our model, a vehicle can have many locations and one or more current locations. In Oracle, we had setup a View that managed the current locations by doing the following in the view definition:

```
SELECT LOCATION_ID, VEHICLE_ID, TIME (
  FROM SELECT LOCATION ID, VEHICLE_ID, TIME, 
    MAX(TIME) OVER (PARTITION BY VEHICLE_ID) AS MAX_TIME FROM LOCATION)
WHERE TIME = MAX_TIME ORDER BY VEHICLE_ID
```

In Orient DB, I've created two Vertex Types: Vehicle and Location and an Edge Type of hasLocation with indexes on VEHICLE_ID, LOCATION_ID, LOCATION_TIME, hasLocation.in and hasLocation.out. I've been able to get the correct result, but not entirely what we need.

```
SELECT in.LOCATION_ID as LOCATION_ID from hasLocation where out.VEHICLE_ID = 'Vehicle-12'
AND in.TIME in (
  SELECT max(OUT('hasLocation').TIME) as MAX_TIME FROM VEHICLE WHERE
    uuid = 'Vehicle-12')
```

I'm still very early in development so I'm trying to figure out the best way to lay out the data and still to get what we need. Our current model has around 50k vehicles with 10M locations and growing quickly. 
I’m able to get the data for one vehicle with the above implementation, but another common request would be something like “What are the current locations for 100 vehicles?”(and page for 101-200) or “given 100 vehicle IDs, what are their current locations?”

Any help on how better to layout the Vertices and Edges and what a better sql function might look like to get the data I need would be greatly appreciated. I also played around with creating the locations as a LinkSet/List, I just don’t know what the best “graph db” layout might be.
Thank you.

Comment: Can you post the schema of the classes Location and Vehicle ?

Comment: I am running a very basic test schema to figure out the best way to model this particular relationship. There's nothing other than Location and Vehicle vertices and hasLocation edge as described above.

Comment: I also did come up with a solution that I'm not sure is the best option. I'm using the above SELECT in.LOCATION_ID code as a javascript function and I created a second function that gets a list of vehicle IDs and sends those vehicle IDs one at a time to the above function. It just seems like there should be a better way to model this in the graph.